# Why are new lines being added automatically when I insert backticks?

Tags: line-breaks

I'm running gVim 7.4 on Windows 7.

I'm editing a text file and I insert text like the following:

```
 1 - public SomeResult GenerateResult(IInput input, Action<string> forEachEventAction)
```

If I add a `` ` `` before `public` and after the closing parenthesis then a new line is automatically inserted, resulting in this:

```
 1 - `public SomeResult GenerateResult(IInput input, Action<string>
forEachEventAction)`
```

Interestingly, my real text (code) is split into several lines, not just two, tho the only difference from the above is that the identifiers are much longer.

`:set all` includes:

```
...
  formatoptions=tcq
...
  textwidth=78
```

Comment: I don't reproduce, can you give a little more infos about your edition ?

Comment: Perhaps you have autoformat on: `:h autoformat` and `set formatoptions?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to my editing a file with a *.txt* extension. You might notice that I'm using Markdown syntax in my example. I've been mostly editing *.md* files previously.

Based on my `formatoptions` setting, text is auto-wrapped using `textwidth`, hence the new lines (and the different number of new lines depending on the length of the text).

The auto-formatting also was unrelated to backtick characters specifically.